# browsers with css focus selector

Tags: focus, selector

I'm having issue with a css rule i wrote, the issue is that the rule works
with IE but doesn't work with any other browser. 
the rule looks like this ->

```
.ui-toggle:focus .toggleMsg, .ui-toggle:focus .toggleAcc, .toggleAcc:hover,
.toggleMsg:hover {display:block}
```

my aim here is to turn either toggleMsg class or toggleAcc class to display:block
it works fine only with IE, if i change the .ui-toggle:focus to .ui-toggle:hover
then when I hover I get display:block rule to kick in.
I have uploaded a minified version of my code to http://www.incapsulatest.tk/test
if anyone has any idea why using :hover works while :focus only works with ie
that would be great

Comment: Just looked at the page in Chrome, Opera & IE. I can't see any difference in appearance or behaviour. Given that the element with ui-toggle as a class is a div, I expect you can't use :focus since it's not an input element. Hover works for everything, as far as I can remember.

Comment: when u click message at the example site with IE do u get a white div showing below it? i do, and the same thing doesn't happen with firefox / safari opera everything besides ie

Comment: this is the way and why (tabindex + pure css solution)  
http://www.barryvan.com.au/2009/01/onfocus-and-onblur-for-divs-in-fx/

Comment: Interesting enough, it's a fizzle when I try IE and Opera. It only works for me with Chrome.

Comment: what are u getting? it works fine for me with safari + chrome + i.e.